# CUDA: Sample code has 300% multi GPU scaling / Performance optimization

Tags: performance, optimization, cuda

I am working on porting a NBody problem solving code to GPUs with CUDA.

Nvidia provides in the samples that come with the CUDA SDK an NBody solving simulation. It is in samples/5_Simulations/nbody.

I am no expert in C++ or CUDA and have a hard time understanding their code spread out in several files so I eventually decided to write my own implementation of their algorithm described in http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/5_Simulations/nbody/doc/nbody_gems3_ch31.pdf.

My implementation was quickly succesful and I was able to compute 25 billion double precision interactions per second on a GTX Titan. When I run their implementation with -benchmark -fp64 I get the same performance. This is surprising to me because in the article I linked above they reached 10 billion single precision interactions per second on a 200Gflop (single precision) card. The GTX titan is about 1.3 Tflops (double precision) therefore I was expecting 65 billion interactions per second in double precision.

To add to the mystery when I run their implementation with -benchmark -fp64 -numdevices=6 computation is 18 times faster. Which amounts to 300% scaling??? Adding more work for the GPU by setting -numbodies ten times larger than its default yields 450% scaling???

I should add that I am running the nbody implementation from the CUDA SDK version 5.5 and that the system is based of 6 identical GTX titans.

I have tried many things to get past 25 billion interactions on my single GPU code but it really seems to be at it's peak as memory accesses are near 100% efficiency according to nvvp and occupancy is at 50% (all attempts to increase it have done nothing for performance).

Are there any mecanisms that can allow GPUs to have 300% scaling?

Is my code really as optimized as can be when I was expecting it to run 2-3 times faster judging by flops?

Is the sample provided with cuda bugged?

Just in case here is a simple version of the kernel:

```
__global__
void Force_GPU(double4 *d_r,double3 *d_F){
    unsigned int idx=threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int index=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+idx;
    __shared__ double4 sharedpos[tilesize];
    double4 position=d_r[index];
    double3 temp_r,force={0.0,0.0,0.0};
    double temp_d;
    #pragma unroll
    for(int tile=0;tile<numtiles;tile++){
        sharedpos[idx]=d_r[tile*tilesize+idx];
        __syncthreads();
        #pragma unroll
        for(int j=0;j<tilesize;j++){
            temp_r.x = position.x -sharedpos[j].x;
            temp_r.y = position.y -sharedpos[j].y;
            temp_r.z = position.z -sharedpos[j].z;
            temp_d = temp_r.x * temp_r.x + temp_r.y * temp_r.y + temp_r.z * temp_r.z+1e-23;
            temp_d = rsqrt(temp_d);
            temp_d *= temp_d*temp_d;
            temp_d *=sharedpos[j].w;
            force.x += temp_r.x * temp_d;
            force.y += temp_r.y * temp_d;
            force.z += temp_r.z * temp_d;
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    d_F[index]=force;
}
```

I have more confusing ones that optimize memory flow and get rid of the softening parameter 1e-23 but performance impact is none existant for the memory optimizations (not alot of data I think) and small (but clear) by getting rid of the softening parameter (which requires more complicated control flow to avoid calculating the force of a particle on itself). As I said I also attempted to increase occupancy but it's limited by registers at 1024 threads out of 2048 per SM. Forcing lower register usage yielded pitiful performance and also required messing around with the tiles to reduce shared memory usage.

Any help and input will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the sample provided with cuda bugged?

I believe there was/is a bug in the nbody sample code up through CUDA 5.5 that begins to take effect with 4 GPUs or more in a multi-GPU setup (may even be with 2 GPUs or more).  You can get some indication of this by running the nbody sample code with `cuda-memcheck`, I think.

It may be fixed in the CUDA 6 RC drop that is currently available, I haven't checked it.

Comment: I tried running cuda-memcheck on it with 2,4 and 6 GPUs and it didn't report any errors. I also tried to run it with the options --flush-to-disk yes and --leak-check full.

Comment: Try the nbody that comes with CUDA 6 RC, which is [available for public download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-pre-production).  In particular, there are significant source code changes in `bodysystemcuda.cu`, connected to multi-device usage, which relate to the bug I am referring to.